# How to deal with libraries' incompatible dependencies in maven while running unit tests?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, dependencies, classloader

I'm trying to run a unit test that uses both `libraryA` and `libraryB`.

LibraryA has a dependency on `com.oldlib:dependencyX:2.0`.   LibraryB has a dependency on `com.newlib:dependencyX:3.0`.

Note `dependencyX` 2.0 and 3.0 are the same library but the groupID got changed between releases (not sure if this is relevant).  Internal package names are the same between 2 and 3.

`dependencyX` has had API changes between 2.0.   If I force maven (with dependency/exclusion) to only use `dependencyX:2.0`, libraryB throws class-not-found exceptions for new classes in 3.0.   If I force maven to use only `dependencyX:3.0`, libraryA throws method-not-found exceptions because some APIs were removed between 2.0 and 3.0.

Is there any to isolate these in a unit test?   I know about OSGI - it would be really neat if maven could seamlessly isolate dependencies into separate classloaders in an osgi-like manner without actually having to set up all the osgi stuff.

(the guilty libraries are apache storm 0.10.0 and cassandra-unit, and the guilty dependency is com.lmax:disruptor / com.googlecode:disruptor).

Comment: As this a very uncommon situation i am not sure about this, but: What about  using [the surefire plugins mechanism to influence the test-classpath](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#classpathDependencyExcludes) to exclude the conflicting dependencies from the classpath for the plugins execution. Combined with several [executions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) you could maybe reach your goal.

Comment: what about refactoring the concerned test case in two tests, one per library, would that be possible?